# How can I use 'body-parser' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I am studying Web server through Node.js.
When I try to use Body-parser, I can't progress anymore.
Status Codes are successful.
It seems to be successful. I got response message. But it doesn't show on browser.

What is the problem?
My code is below.

```
//basic-server.js

const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express()

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

const PORT = 5000;
const ip = 'localhost';

app.use(cors())

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
  res.send("hello")
})

app.post('/lower', jsonParser, (req, res) =>{
  
 res.send(req.body.body.toLowerCase())
  
})
app.post('/upper', jsonParser, (req, res) =>{
  
  res.send(req.body.body.toUpperCase())
})



app.listen(PORT, ip, () => {
  console.log(`http server listen on ${ip}:${PORT}`);
});
```

```
// App.js

class App {
  init() {
    document
      .querySelector('#to-upper-case')
      .addEventListener('click', this.toUpperCase.bind(this));
    document
      .querySelector('#to-lower-case')
      .addEventListener('click', this.toLowerCase.bind(this));
  }
  post(path, body) {
    
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/${path}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({body}),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        return res.json()})
      .then(res => {  
        this.render(res);
      });
  }
  toLowerCase() {
    const text = document.querySelector('.input-text').value;
    this.post('lower', text);
  }
  toUpperCase() {
    const text = document.querySelector('.input-text').value;
    this.post('upper', text);
  }
  render(response) {
    const resultWrapper = document.querySelector('#response-wrapper');
    document.querySelector('.input-text').value = '';
    resultWrapper.innerHTML = response;
  }
}

const app = new App();
app.init();
```

The error message on console of developer tool

```
'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
Promise.then (async)
post @ App.js:21
toUpperCase @ App.js:31'.
```

Below information is from network tab.

```
-preflight
Request URL: http://localhost:5000/upper
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 No Content
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:5000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 28 May 2021 10:15:31 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:5000
Origin: null
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36
```

```
-fetch
Request URL: http://localhost:5000/upper
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:5000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 28 May 2021 10:15:31 GMT
ETag: W/"1-bc1M4j2I4u6VaLpUbAB8Y9kTHBs"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 12
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:5000
Origin: null
Pragma: no-cache
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36
{body: "a"}
body: "a"
```

```
-Response
A
```

Comment: How do you call `post` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `bodyparser` correctly. The problem is in your code, you are returning just a symbol `A`, and the client trying to parse this that is incorrect JSON, that is why it fails.

You can change  `res.send(req.body.body.toUpperCase())` to  `res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body.body.toUpperCase()))` to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

the response you got is not a json format so try add this in your code above the requestes in server.js  ;

```js
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
```

if it workes then the problem that you are sending an other format not json so jason parser will not work .